# Drupal multisite databases not being displayed in PHPMyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, multisite, drupal-9, lando

Created Drupal 9 multisite with 2 subsites successfully
Created a separate database for each site
Logged in to PHPMyadmin databases for 2 subsites are not displayed there. Databases are present in MariaDB.
However, a database for the main site is present as it is.

Lando version: **v3.1.4**

Here is .lando.yml

```
name: healsecurity_lando
recipe: drupal9
config:
  webroot: web
  php: '7.4'
  composer_version: '2.1.9'
  # via: apache:2.4
  via: nginx
  database: mariadb:10.4
  xdebug: false
services:
  phpmyadmin:
    type: phpmyadmin
    hosts:
      - database
  subsite1:
    type: mariadb:10.4
    portforward: true
    creds:
      user: drupal9
      password: drupal9
      database: subsite1
  subsite2:
    type: mariadb:10.4
    portforward: true
    creds:
      user: drupal9
      password: drupal9
      database: subsite2
proxy:
  appserver_nginx:
    - main.lndo.site
    - subsite1.lndo.site
    - subsite2.lndo.site
```

Attached is the screenshot of PHPMyadmin

[image]
Please let me know if I am missing any configurations.

Thanks
Prashant

Comment: It worked by adding the service name to the list of hosts "subsite1" is my service name, you can get the service name by "lando info" command.
services:
  phpmyadmin:
    type: phpmyadmin
    hosts:
      - database
      - subsite1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by adding the service name to the list of hosts. "subsite1" is my service name, you can get the service name by "lando info" command.

```
services:
  phpmyadmin:
    type: phpmyadmin
    hosts:
      - database
      - subsite1
```